# Explode and labels for nested kendo donut charts using jQuery

Tags: jquery, charts, kendo-ui, donut-chart

I need Nested donut charts with following 2 requirements:

1. Labels displayed outside for the outer Donut & not visible for the inner donut. I can make it visible outside for the outer Donut. But, for the inner one, Label appears on the Donut itself.

My expectation is:

[image: Expectation]
I could achieve:

[image: Achieved]

2. Clicked section of the donut chart should be exploded. I am able to achieve this for the outer Donut but not for the inner donut.
   Same I am expecting for the inner Donut click as well:

[image]

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <base href="http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/donut-charts/index">
    <style>html { font-size: 14px; font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; }</style>
    <title></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2016.2.504/styles/kendo.common.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2016.2.504/styles/kendo.flat.min.css" />

    <script src="//kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2016.2.504/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="//kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2016.2.504/js/kendo.all.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="example">
    <div class="demo-section k-content wide">
        <div id="chart" style="background: center no-repeat url('../content/shared/styles/world-map.png');"></div>
    </div>
    <script>
        function createChart() {
        var dataForNestedDonut = [
            {
                "series": 'status',
                "source": "New",
                "percentage": 22,
                "color": "#9de219",
                "explode": false,
                "labelVisibility": true
            }, {
                "series": 'status',
                "source": "Pending",
                "percentage": 29,
                "color": "#90cc38",
                "explode": false,
                "labelVisibility": true
            }, {
                "series": 'status',
                "source": "In-Progress",
                "percentage": 49,
                "color": "#068c35",
                "explode": false,
                "labelVisibility": true
            },{   
                "series": 'SLA',
                "source": "SLA Due",
                "percentage": 20,
                "color": "#FF0000",
                "explode": false,
                "labelVisibility": false
            }, {
                "series": 'SLA',
                "source": "No SLA",
                "percentage": 32,
                "color": "#f5deb3",
                "explode": false,
                "labelVisibility": false
            }, {
                "series": 'SLA',
                "source": "SLA Warning",
                "percentage": 48,
                "color": "#FFFF00",
                "explode": false,
                "labelVisibility": false
            }];

        $("#chart").kendoChart({
            legend: {
                visible: false,
            },
            seriesDefaults: {
                type: "donut",
                overlay: { gradient: "none" },
                labels: {
                    visible: true,
                    background: "transparent"
                },
                visual: function (e) {
                    e.options.highlight.border.width = 20;
                    e.options.highlight.border.color = "black";
                    return e.createVisual();
                }
            },
            dataSource: {
                data: dataForNestedDonut,
                group: {
                    field: "series"
                }
            },
            series: [{
                field: "percentage",
                categoryField: "source",
                colorField: "color",
                explodeField: "explode",
                // Need wo implement something like this
                //labelVisibleField: "labelVisibility",
                labels: {
                    position: "outsideEnd",
                    template: "#= category # \n #= value #",
                    visible: true,
                    background: "transparent",
                },
                // padding: 10
            },
            ],

            tooltip: {
                visible: true,
                template: "${ category } - ${ value }%"
            },
            seriesClick: function (e) {
                $.each(e.sender.dataSource.view(), function () {
                    $.each(this.items, function () {
                        this.explode = false;
                    })                    
                });
                e.sender.options.transitions = false;
                // Not working for the inner Donut
                e.dataItem.explode = true;
                e.sender.refresh();
                //alert(`identifier: ${e.dataItem.identifier} \n ${e.series.name} \n ${e.dataItem.source} \n ${e.dataItem.percentage}`);
            },
        });
        }
        $(document).ready(createChart);
        $(document).bind("kendo:skinChange", createChart);
    </script>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Any suggestion on how can I achieve these

Comment: I could achieve the 1st requirement of hiding Labels for the inner Donut using below snippet : 
              
                var chart = $("#chart").data("kendoChart");
                chart.options.series[0].labels.visible = false
                chart.redraw();
But couldn't achieve the 2nd requirement

Comment: $("#chart").kendoChart({
    ...
    series: [{
        ...
        labels: {
            visible: false,
   ...
        }
    }],
    render: function (e) {
        var index = e.sender.options.series.length - 1;
        if (e.sender.options.series[index].labels.visible != true) {
            e.sender.options.series[index].labels.visible = true;
            e.sender.redraw();
        }
    }
});